# Why is Ant's default exclude not working?

Tags: ant, jenkins

I'm using Ant for "Continous integration". One of my tasks is copying folders from one point to another. Here is my task.

```
<target name="copy-new">
    <copy todir="/files/apps/blog/" verbose="true">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <exclude name="**/.git" />
            <exclude name="**/.gitignore" />
            <exclude name="**/pom.xml" />
            <exclude name="**/build.xml" />
            <exclude name="**/readme" />
            <exclude name="**/tmp" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

As [the official documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes) says, there are default excludes such a .git folder etc.

But my logs are showing this : (there are many more)

```
...
[copy] Copying /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/blog/workspace/.git/objects/19/5d7e2de34db6ecc5078c477eb26d0684f68bb7 to /files/apps/blog/.git/objects/19/5d7e2de34db6ecc5078c477eb26d0684f68bb7
...
```

How to add these files to ignore filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
<target name="copy-new">
    <copy todir="/files/apps/blog/" verbose="true">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <exclude name="**/.git/**" />
            <exclude name="**/.gitignore" />
            <exclude name="**/pom.xml" />
            <exclude name="**/build.xml" />
            <exclude name="**/readme" />
            <exclude name="**/tmp/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Comment: Why are the default excludes not used by ant? As `**/.git/**` figures in the default?

Comment: You might be using an older version of `ant`. This is only since 1.8.2.

Comment: Nope, freshly installed. Version 1.8.2.

Comment: Oh, my error. I seem to have several versions of Ant installed. And indeed, the one executing this task was on 1.8.0.